# Hive coalesce parse exception

Tags: hive

I want to create a hive script that uses as database one of two given parameters, whichever is not null.

My `hive-test.sql` is this:

```
set db_name = coalesce(${hiveconf:dbOne}, ${hiveconf:dbTwo});
use ${hiveconf:db_name};
show tables;
```

and I run it with:

```
hive -hiveconf dbOne=my_database -f hive-test.sql
```

and I am getting:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 2:12 missing EOF at '(' near 'coalesce'
```

I should note that if I change the first line in script to:

```
set db_name = my_database;
```

it works.

I can't figure out what I did wrong. Your assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in Hive.

Do variable assignment in the shell, for example like here: [setting-a-shell-variable-in-a-null-coalescing-fashion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62333/setting-a-shell-variable-in-a-null-coalescing-fashion) and pass it to the Hive.